# How to redirect to specefic folder in apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to make a .htaccess file that when URL is ru/ redirect to ru/ directory and if URL is anything else go to public/ directory

Comment: If the URL is already `ru/`, how can you want it to redirect to the same thing? Please review and clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect everything to public dir except /ru , you can use the following rule

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ru [NC]
RewriteRule !public /public/ [L]
```